# Bash can't find go exectuable after installing Go package for OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, path

I installed Go (programming language) to Max OS X but "go version" in terminal gives

> -bash: go: command not found

Echoing `$PATH` returns:

```
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/user/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
```

What do I need to change to start using Go?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: The installer linked here: http://www.golang-book.com/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Go should be installed to either `/usr/local/go/bin` or `~/Go/bin` — I can't test the installer now.

Try editing your `~/.bash_profile` by calling:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Then adding:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Save the file by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>, then <kbd>↩</kbd>, and reload your shell (e.g. by restarting the Terminal). Now, `go` should work as a command, assuming it is provided as `/usr/local/go/bin/go`.

Comment: I cannot find **/usr/local/go**.  What if I used GVM?

Comment: GVM should install into `~/.gvm`, but I have never used it. If even the `gvm` command is not working for you, perhaps it's better to raise an issue here: https://github.com/moovweb/gvm — or look at the documentation. Maybe something went wrong during the installation.